# Conjectures about the harmonic series and also about infinite geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering if there are any (of course unproved)conjectures about the harmonic series and infinite geometric series that are of some importance to the mathematics community. Kindly share if you know of any. Thank you all.

Comment: [This problem](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/elementaryrh.pdf) has attracted some attention over the years.

Comment: That's strange.  It works here.  Google "An elementary problem equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis."

Comment: Thanks once again @saulspartz. It works now.